# How would you solve these logarithmic problems

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

Problem 1

[image]

Problem 2:

IF 5^X = 15 then what would be 5^2x-1

Comment: Dear Ben, what are your ideas on problem number two? Can you use division rules to express $5^{2x-1}$ in terms of $5^x$?

Comment: How come $\log1$ suddenly turned into $\log10$?  What is $\log1$ anyway?

Comment: Is it $5^{2x}-1$ or $5^{2x-1}$?

Comment: As well as other errors, in lines 4 and 5 it looks like you think if logarithms are too hard you can just drop them.  You **seriously** need to talk to your teacher about this, you are not going to understand it from online replies.

Answer (score 0):

Problem 2:

$5^{2x-1} = \frac{(5^x)^2}{5}$

So if you know $5^x$, you can get the rest.

Problem 1:

$\log(1) = 0 $
So any real solutions come from $x^2+4x-60 = 0$ or $x^2 -5x +5 = 1$